# Unsubscribe with no standard unsubscribe link

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe

we have a Marketing Cloud email with a custom unsubscribe link.
When clicking on this link, contacts are redirected to a cloud page where they can manage their preferences and, if willing, perform a complete unsubscribe.
Since we are using this custom link, the Marketing Cloud standard unsubscribe link is not present in the email.
However, some contacts seem to have performed the standard unsubscribe. They didn't report the email as spam, but when looking at the tracking of the email we can see that they unsubscribed from the Subscription Center.
When using the custom link, contacts are not listed among the unsubscribes in the Tracking Sends report.

We cannot understand why we see these contacts as having performed the standard unsubscribe.
Could it be that blocking the sender in their inbox (without reporting the email as spam) is tracked in Marketing Cloud as an unsubscribe from the Subscription Center?

Comment: list header unsub is my bet if this is a commercial send

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to find the unsubscribe reason by checking the [_BusinessUnitUnsubscribes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5) Data View. But here are some of the common reasons why this could be happening:

**Email Header Unsubscribe**: This happens when a subscriber unsubscribes from the gmail header, when it receives the email. This will unsubscribe the customer in 'All Subscribers'List.

**RMM Unsubscribe**: This happens when a subscriber unsubscribes by replying to the email with words like 'Unsubscribe, Unsub" , when it receives the email. This will unsubscribe the customer in 'All Subscribers' List.(Provided you have RMM enabled)

Comment: The unsubscribe reason is "Unsubscribed from the Subscription Center". There is no RMM enabled and the email addresses are not from Gmail. Anyway, I didn't know about the header unsubscribe, thanks! Maybe it happens with other ESPs too.

Comment: Yes it can happen with other ESPs

Comment: You can check the documentation on this topic from SFMC: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386352&type=1